# How to delete multiple selected item in a listBox - with Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

For deleting items from my listBox I use a loop but it delete only the firt selected item. I can't use `Listbox.delete(i,j,k)` because i can't pass my tuple 'index' as argument for Listbox.delete().
Need help please.

```
def App():
root=Tk()
operatorList=tk.Listbox(root,selectmode="MULTIPLE")
operatorList.pack()

#binding the Listbox
conn = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/Stagiaire/Desktop/Ketrika/VCbase.db')
cursor=conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT operatorId,operatorName from Operator")
OpRecord=cursor.fetchall()
conn.close()
i=0
for operator in OpRecord:
    operatorList.insert(i,operator)
    i=i+1
workingOperator=[]

def CmdSelect():
    index=operatorList.curselection()
    for i in index:
        o=operatorList.get(i)
        workingOperator.append(o)
        operatorList.delete(i)
    
SelectButton=Button(root,text="Select",command=SelectCmd)   
SelectButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have actually deleted the number of items you have selected, but not the items you expect.  It is because after you delete the first selected item, the index of the remaining items have been changed.  Then when you delete the second selected item, it will delete the item behind it actually.

You need to delete the items in reverse order:

```py
def CmdSelect():
    tmp = []
    for i in operatorList.curselection()[::-1]:
        tmp.append(operatorList.get(i))
        operatorList.delete(i)
    workingOperator.extend(tmp)
```

Comment: The most effective solution I can hope for ! thank you :)